# Conversion of 3B2 to LaTeX

Tags: conversion

My publisher 10 years ago did my book in 3B2, much to my displeasure. Now I'm stuck with 3B2 files instead of something I can edit. Is there software that can convert 3B2 files to LaTeX, or must one create LaTeX source from scratch?

Comment: What is 3B2? Any pointers/links?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek http://gpsl.co/3b2/

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. It seems to be based on XML/SGML/..., thus there might be some hope for some kind of transforming the data to other formats. It also depends, how the text is written, with visual markup (e.g., `\textbf`, `\textit` in LaTeX), or with logical markup (e.g., `\section`, `\begin{equation}` in LaTeX). Also the difficulty depends on the features used in the book like footnotes, math, fancy formatting.

Comment: 3b2 (now called APP) is a general SGML/XML typesetting tool, so the difficulty or not of converting to tex depends on the particular sgml format used. On the plus side the math markup (and renderer) in 3b2 _is_  TeX so you should be able to extract any math fragments as tex source.